# Unable to get total count in my query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is my query for getting total count.

```
SELECT       
    MemberShipMaster.Id,   
    MemberShipMaster.Name,  
    TotalCount = 
    (
        SELECT
            ISNULL(COUNT(MemberPortfolio.Id), 0) AS total
        FROM
            JFPMembers
            INNER JOIN MemberPortfolio 
                ON JFPMembers.MemberID = MemberPortfolio.MemberId
        WHERE
            JFPMembers.MembershipType = MemberShipMaster.Id 
            AND JFPMembers.IsActive = 1
            AND MemberPortfolio.IsActive = 1
    )  
FROM
    MemberShipMaster
    Left JOIN JFPMembers
        ON MemberShipMaster.Id = JFPMembers.MembershipType   
WHERE
    MemberShipMaster.Id <> 6
GROUP BY
    MemberShipMaster.Id,
    MemberShipMaster.Name
Order by
    MemberShipMaster.Name
```

Below are my table schema

```
SELECT [MemberID]        -- PK 
    ,[MembershipType]  --FK , table [MemberShipMaster]
FROM JFPMembers

SELECT [Id]       -- PK
    ,[MemberId] -- FK OF Table JFPMembers         
FROM MemberPortfolio

SELECT [Id]  --PK
    ,[Name]
FROM MemberShipMaster
```

What I need is the Total Count of member Portfolios , by MembershipType, i.e my relationship is something like this, JFPMembers is primary table for holding member info. There are 3 categories of members, Premium, Corporate and General. These three types are stored in MemberShipMaster. Ids are 3,4,and 5 respectively. There is one more table for holding Portfolio which as MemberId to relate its respective member.

But I am getting some multi valued or reference error with MemberShipMaster.Id . Please help me...

Comment: Could you please disclose exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Code:

```
SELECT abb1.Id, abb1.Name,   
TotalCount =  
(SELECT 
        ISNULL(COUNT(abb3.Id), 0) AS total 
    FROM 
        JFPMembers as abb4 
        INNER JOIN MemberPortfolio as abb3 
            ON abb4.MemberID = abb3.MemberId 
    WHERE 
        abb4.MembershipType = abb1.Id  
        AND abb4.IsActive = 1 
        AND abb3.IsActive = 1)   

FROM 
    MembershipMaster as abb1 
    Left JOIN JFPMembers as abb2
        ON abb1.Id = abb2.MembershipType    
WHERE 
    abb1.Id <> 6 
GROUP BY 
    abb1.Id, 
    abb1.Name 
Order by 
    abb1.Name
```

Comment: It is dependent on MemberShipmaster: `JFPMembers.MembershipType = MemberShipMaster.Id `

Comment: Add aliases to all instances of the tables you are using.  I've edited the code above to reflect this